# How to use logback + slf4j in a Spring Boot war application deployed on JBoss EAP7 - Currently it doesn't log anything

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, logback, slf4j, jboss-eap-7

I have a Spring Boot (1.5.10) War application deployed on JBoss EAP7.0. I have left all the logging configuration as it comes with Spring Boot. I want to specify the log levels and the rest of the stuff using the `logging.xxx` properties, not the logback xml file.

The point is JBoss starts and prints up to here:

```
14:04:19,866 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) 14:04:19.865 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 68] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with 'servletContextInitParams'
Connected to server
[2018-02-05 02:04:39,152] Artifact Gradle : xxx : yyy-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2018-02-05 02:04:55,092] Artifact Gradle : xxx : yyy-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-02-05 02:04:55,092] Artifact Gradle : xxx : yyy-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Deploy took 15,940 milliseconds
```

Then the Spring Boot application should be tracing but there's nothing in the console, nor in the server.log file

If I deploy it on a Tomcat server it works OK.

I have tried several things, including setting this in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but none of them work:

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    <module name="org.slf4j" />
    <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />
```

Comment: What does your `logback.xml` look like and are you including logback in your deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the issue, but have you changed your JBoss per deployment logging settings? If you set a JBoss vm arg like this: `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` it will disable your app-specific logger settings and use the settings defined by JBoss in your `$EAP_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`

If that's not the issue though, you may want to turn that vm arg on to test if jboss itself will at least log correctly for your app to help narrow down your issue. More info: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your parent package and log level in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml as mentioned below

```
<logger category="com.iedr">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

Here my parent package is com.iedr and log level i wanted is INFO.
You should add this one to your logging subsystem, as mentioned below

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
<logger category="com.arjuna">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="sun.rmi">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger category="com.iedr">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
<root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
<formatter name="PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```